# How to replace the number in a string with corresponding image name, title, description

Tags: php

I have a string like this

```
$desc = "Following is the nutritional management of children with Crohn’s disease and 
ulcerative colitis. Avoid Food Sensitivities Many times, it is observed that the children 
suffering from inflammatory bowel diseases develop intolerances towards certain foods. 
Maintaining a proper food diary helps to eliminate food sensitivities.

{{5}}

Consume Lactose-Free Foods Many children are unable to tolerate foods rich in lactose like 
milk and milk products due to the inflammatory bowel disease. Hence, instead of consuming 
cow’s milk which is rich in lactose, almond milk or soy milk can be consumed.

{{1}}";
```

And my array is

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [blog_id] => 2
        [filename] => 6020e71c957ab.jpg
        [w] => 800
        [h] => 400
        [pos_id] => 1
        [title] => First Banner Title
        [description] => First Banner Description
        [created_at] => 2021-02-08 12:54:12
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [blog_id] => 2
        [filename] => 6020e7ce20d3b.jpg
        [w] => 1200
        [h] => 800
        [pos_id] => 5
        [title] => Second Banner Title
        [description] => Second Banner Description
        [created_at] => 2021-02-08 12:57:10
    )
```

)

My query is i need to replace the string {{5}} And {{1}}  where {{5}} And {{1}}  is pos_id of an array,

If i **echo** the **final variable** means my **sample output format** is

Following is the nutritional management of children with Crohn’s disease and ulcerative colitis. Avoid Food Sensitivities Many times, it is observed that the children suffering from inflammatory bowel diseases develop intolerances towards certain foods. Maintaining a proper food diary helps to eliminate food sensitivities.
6020e7ce20d3b.jpg (Image shown here) (And title of the image and description)
Consume Lactose-Free Foods Many children are unable to tolerate foods rich in lactose like milk and milk products due to the inflammatory bowel disease. Hence, instead of consuming cow’s milk which is rich in lactose, almond milk or soy milk can be consumed.
6020e71c957ab.jpg (Image shown here) (And title of the image and description)**

Kindly help me to fix this
Thanks..

Comment: Please show your code attempt. Hint: Use regex to find '{{n}}'. Then search in your array and do the replacement. If you have many replacements to do, consider creating a mapTable for faster finding.

Comment: I attach my sample code here
https://codepen.io/Gautham-Dev/pen/NWbajae

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```php
$desc = "Following is the nutritional management of children with Crohn’s disease and 
ulcerative colitis. Avoid Food Sensitivities Many times, it is observed that the children 
suffering from inflammatory bowel diseases develop intolerances towards certain foods. 
Maintaining a proper food diary helps to eliminate food sensitivities.

{{5}}

Consume Lactose-Free Foods Many children are unable to tolerate foods rich in lactose like 
milk and milk products due to the inflammatory bowel disease. Hence, instead of consuming 
cow’s milk which is rich in lactose, almond milk or soy milk can be consumed.

{{1}}";

$data = [
    [
        "id" => 1,
        "blog_id" => 2,
        "filename" => "6020e71c957ab.jpg",
        "w" => 800,
        "h" => 400,
        "pos_id" => 1,
        "title" => "First Banner Title",
        "description" => "First Banner Description",
        "created_at" => "2021-02-08 12:54:12",
    ],
    [
        "id" => 2,
        "blog_id" => 2,
        "filename" => "6020e7ce20d3b.jpg",
        "w" => 1200,
        "h" => 800,
        "pos_id" => 5,
        "title" => "Second Banner Title",
        "description" => "Second Banner Description",
        "created_at" => "2021-02-08 12:57:10",
    ]
];

// Here I do match your placeholders with named regex groups.
//
// The needle named group will map placeholders like: {{NUMBER}}
// The nested place named group will map the NUMBER part of the placeholder.
preg_match_all("/(?<needle>\{\{(?<place>\d+)\}\})/im", $desc, $matches);

// Here I check if we have groups in our matches
if( isset($matches['needle']) && isset($matches['place']) ) {

    // Then I do iterate over the matches for the need
    foreach($matches['needle'] as $idx => $needle) {

        // I get from the matches the place ID Number
        $place_id = (int)$matches['place'][$idx];

        // And finally, I do filter the data array, to get the entry with the same image pos_id.
        $img = array_filter(
            $data,
            function($entry) use($place_id) {
                return $entry['pos_id'] === $place_id;
            }
        );

        // If for any reason there's no image, then I do continue 
        // with the next match
        if ( 0 === count($img) ) {
            continue;
        }

        $img = array_shift($img);

        // Then I build the HTML that you need to replace the placeholder
        $replace_string = sprintf(
            "%s (%s) (%s and %s)",
            $img['filename'],
            sprintf(
                "<img src=\"%s\" title=\"%s\" />",
                $img['filename'],
                $img['title']
            ),
            $img['title'],
            $img['description']
        );

        // And finally I do the replace in the $desc.
        $desc = str_replace($needle, $replace_string, $desc);
    }
}

echo $desc;
```

and the output in my console is this:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

look at the below, that is  workflow ..Code `{{`  and `}}`
Search and replace beetwen it

[regex link](https://regex101.com/r/wREhNX/1)

```php
$replaced=preg_replace_callback('{{(?<user_id>\d+)}}', static function ($find) {
            $numeric= $find['user_id'];
            return "number is $numeric";
        }, $template);

print_r($repalced);
```